# How do I change the style when feature is modifying and not stop the modify

Tags: styles, openlayers-6

I want to change the style when the feature is modifying, but once the feature's style has been setting, its modify would be stopped, how can I change the style and it still can modify?
here is the code:

```
this.modify.on(['modifystart', 'modifyend'], function (evt) {
            target.style.cursor = evt.type === 'modifystart' ? 'grabbing' : 'pointer'
            const currentFeature = evt.features.array_[0]
            const oldStyle = currentFeature.getStyle()
            console.log(oldStyle)
            console.log(evt.type)
            if (evt.type === 'modifystart') {
                const moveImage = new Image()
                const pinInfo = evt.features.array_[0].get('pinInfo')
                moveImage.src = that.moveIcon
                moveImage.width = 50
                moveImage.height = 70
                moveImage.onload = function () {
                    const iconCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
                    iconCanvas.width = moveImage.width
                    iconCanvas.height = moveImage.height
                    const iconCanvasCtx = iconCanvas.getContext('2d')
                    // 背景アイコンを描画
                    iconCanvasCtx.drawImage(moveImage, 0, -25, 50, 70)
                    const style = new Style({
                         image: new Icon({
                              anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
                              img: iconCanvas,
                              imgSize: [moveImage.width, moveImage.height],
                              scale: that.imgSize / 30
                         })
                    })
                    // const arrayStyle = [style, oldStyle]
                    currentFeature.setStyle(style)  
                }
            } else if (evt.type === 'modifyend') {
                // currentFeature.setStyle(oldStyle)
            }
        })
```

Thanks a lot!